# Assign a ggplot plot to a variable inside a function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to fit a polynomial regression of different orders and plot them on the same plot using `ggplot` and `gridExtra`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

set.seed(123)
x <- 1:10
y <- sin(2*pi*x) + 0.2*rnorm(x)
df <- data.frame(x, y)

for (i in 1:4) {
  pp <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point() +
    stat_smooth(method='lm', formula = y ~ poly(x, i))
  nam <- paste0("p", i)
  assign(nam, pp)
}

grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, nrow=2, ncol=2)
```

Here `i` represents the order of the polynomial, and polynomials up to order 4 are fitted. Strangely, I got the following plot where all four plots are order 4.

I did some research and suspected the reason is related to assigning ggplot object to a variable inside a function. However, I am not sure how to fix it. Help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added `.GlobalEnv` to the `assign` and used `walk` rather than a `for` loop:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)
library(glue)

set.seed(123)
x <- 1:10
y <- sin(2*pi*x) + 0.2*rnorm(x)
df <- data.frame(x, y)

walk(1:4, \(i) {
  nam <- paste0("p", i)

  pp <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
    geom_point() +
    stat_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y ~ poly(x, i)) +
    labs(title = glue("poly {i}"))

  assign(nam, pp, .GlobalEnv)
})

grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, p4, nrow=2, ncol=2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-12 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I like lists of plots; to `grid.arrange` the elements, we can use `do.call()`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
set.seed(123)
df = data.frame(x <- 1L:10L, y = sin(2L*pi*x) + .2*rnorm(x))
g = ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) + geom_point()
X = lapply(seq_len(4L), \(i) {
  g + stat_smooth(method = 'lm', formula = y ~ poly(x, i)) +
    ggtitle(paste("poly", i))
})
do.call(gridExtra::grid.arrange, c(X, nrow = 2L, ncol = 2L))
```

[image]

This allows us to stay well clear of `assign()`.

---

Note. With some work, we can achieve similar results in base R.

```r
# set.seed(123)
# df = data.frame(x <- 1L:10L, y = sin(2L*pi*x) + .2*rnorm(x))
par(mfrow = c(2L, 2L))
for(i in seq_len(4L)) {
  # calc 
  y = predict(lm(y ~ poly(x, i), data = df))
  ix = sort(df$x, index.return = T)$ix
  # plot "base"; dynamic part: title (main)
  plot(df, xlab = "x", ylab = "y", main = paste("poly", i))
  rect(par("usr")[[1L]], par("usr")[[3L]], 
       par("usr")[[2L]], par("usr")[[4L]],
       col = "lightgray")
  grid(nx = NULL, ny = NULL, col = "white", lty = 1L)
  with(df, points(x, y, pch = 20L)) 
  # add lines 
  lines(df$x[ix], y[ix], col = "blue", lwd = 2L)
}
```

[image]

Yet missing: minor grid lines, moving the creation of the "base plot" outside the loop, and CIs.